# Emacs Org-mode - Export dynamically to another directory?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have constructed such function in lisp:

```
(defun set-web-hosting (hosting)
 """ this function sets the hosting of web to specific tramp like target """
(setq org-publish-project-alist
    '(
      ("belohrad.ch-notes"
       :base-directory "~/SVN/fiweb/"
       :base-extension "org"
   :publishing-directory hosting
       :recursive t
       :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
       :headline-levels 999
       :table-of-contents nil
       :section-numbers nil
       :auto-preamble t
       :auto-sitemap t
       :auto-postamble nil
       :style ""
       :sitemap-filename "sitemap.org"
       :sitemap-title "Sitemap"
       :sub-superscript nil
       :author "David Belohrad"
       :email "david@belohrad.ch"
       )
      ("belohrad.ch-static"
       :base-directory "~/SVN/fiweb"
       :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|deb"
   :publishing-directory hosting
       :recursive t
       :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
       )
      ("web" :components ("belohrad.ch-static" "belohrad.ch-notes"))
      )))
```

Thinking, that I can use

```
(set-web-hosting "~/afs/www/org/")
```

to setup my target to the mentioned test directory, and

```
(set-web-hosting ".ssh:nlanla@nlsnls.org:/public_html/")
```

to set it to life web.

This does not work, because 'hosting' is not treated in the function as variable, but 'something else'.
When publishing is called, it finishes with

```
org-publish-file: Wrong type argument: arrayp, hosting
```

How can I correctly setup the `:publishing-directory` property?

Comment: Elisp does not have a special `"""` thingy, so `""" foo """` is understood by Emacs as 3 lists, the first and last being empty.

Answer (score 4):

There is special idiom for manipulating with lisp code, backquote and comma:

```
`(a ,b c)
```

see

```
(describe-function '\`)
```

And your setup is:

```
(defun set-web-hosting (hosting)
  " this function sets the hosting of web to specific tramp like target "
  (eval `(setq org-publish-project-alist
           '(
         ("belohrad.ch-notes"
          :base-directory "~/SVN/fiweb/"
          :base-extension "org"
          :publishing-directory ,hosting
          :recursive t
          :publishing-function org-publish-org-to-html
          :headline-levels 999
          :table-of-contents nil
          :section-numbers nil
          :auto-preamble t
          :auto-sitemap t
          :auto-postamble nil
          :style ""
          :sitemap-filename "sitemap.org"
          :sitemap-title "Sitemap"
          :sub-superscript nil
          :author "David Belohrad"
          :email "david@belohrad.ch"
          )
         ("belohrad.ch-static"
          :base-directory "~/SVN/fiweb"
          :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|deb"
          :publishing-directory ,hosting
          :recursive t
          :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
          )
         ("web" :components ("belohrad.ch-static" "belohrad.ch-notes"))
         ))))
```

Comment: If this answer was useful to you, you might want to accept it (the same goes for answers to your other questions as well) http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask